# Method of programmatically getting CPU time for thread, in C, that works on both OpenSolaris and Linux

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, opensolaris

I have a small daemon that I'm writing in C and I need a way to get the current CPU time on a thread. Linux apparently supplies a number of ways to go about doing this, clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, ...), pthread_getcpuclockid(), getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, ...) but none of these seem to be supported under OpenSolaris 2009.06.

Is there a cross-platform friendly way to get the current CPU time for a thread? If not, is there any way to do it in OpenSolaris at all? At this point, I'm even willing to put in a bunch of ugly compiler directives to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ["Thread Priority on the Solaris Platform"](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/thread-priorities.html), Solaris 9 and above default to a one-to-one correspondence between threads and LWPs ([Light-Weight Processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_process)).   Therefore, according to [getrusage's manpage](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/getrusage-3c.html#scrolltoc), you should be able to call `getrusage(RUSAGE_LWP, ...)`.